# Sum totals based on column name?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet which figures are manually entered in to in order to record activity across a variety of sites. The sheet contains a date column with each date as a row value. It then has three columns (Total tests, Total positives, Total voids) which are repeated for each site. There are 10 sites (which will grow) so for not there are 10 total tests, 10 total positives, 10 total void columns.

What I would like to do is sum a total based on the column name so that each day, it is automatically adding the total tests across all the sites, the total positives and total voids.

I tried using a SUM calculated field on a pivot table but when I did this, using 'Total tests', it only picked up the first column with this name and did not sum all of the columns with that name.

Is there a way using a pivot table (or alternative means) to sum the daily totals for those columns with the same name?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RBYPLy5MEeAljz92_wbtHNC-tlHqxNzfSwGr2mE1zMw/edit?usp=sharing 

Here it is

Answer (score 1):

your sheet has a predictive layout (eg. each site has always 3 columns) so you can sue `MOD` of 3 to always get every 3rd column and sum them:

AH3:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF), 3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
               FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF), 3)=0)), 1, 1, 0)))
```

AI3:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-1, 3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
               FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-1, 3)=0)), 1, 1, 0)))
```

AJ3:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-2, 3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
               FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-2, 3)=0)), 1, 1, 0)))
```

[image]

to remove zeros you can do this in AH3:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF), 3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
                            FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF), 3)=0)), 1, 1, 0)))))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({IF(A3:A<>"",ISOWEEKNUM(A3:A),),
 MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF),   3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
         FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF),   3)=0)), 1, 1, 0)), 
 MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-1, 3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
         FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-1, 3)=0)), 1, 1, 0)),
 MMULT(1*FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-2, 3)=0), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(
         FILTER(C3:AF, MOD(COLUMN(C:AF)-2, 3)=0)), 1, 1, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's so helpful! Is it possible to amend the formula so that it calculates weekly totals (as per the ISOWEEKNUM column) instead of daily, whist removing 0s?

Comment: Thank you, that's incredibly helpful. One last question, I just realised that in my actual data, there is some data in there from last year (I have added an example to the sheet I shared) that needs to be in the sheet but I do not want to count it in my weekly totals.

So in column AL, I want to count week 1 & 2 but not week 53/anything from 2020. Is it possible to adjust the formula to do this?

Comment: Is it possible with ISOWEEKNUM as opposed to regular WEEKNUM? For the purposes of what I am doing, the weeks need to start on Mondays so 04/01 needs to be week 1 etc.

Comment: yes that is possible but in that case you will sill get weeknum 53 because first 3 days of this year 2021 are in ISO standard considered as 53rd week of previous year

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, instead of being YEAR>2020 could it be an equivalent of DATE>03/01/21 so it wouldn't pick up anything pre ISOWEEK 1? (I did try this and couldn't get it to work)

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thank you :)